# Justifying property about sets in the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> **Theorem 2.40** Suppose $E\in \mathcal{L}^n$. Then $\mathcal{m}(E)= \inf \{\mathcal{m}(U):U\supset E , U \text{ open}\}$
>
> *Proof.* By the definition of product measures, if $E\in \mathcal{L}^n$  and $\epsilon>0$ there is a countable family $\{T_j\}$
> of rectangles such that $E\subset \bigcup_1^\infty T_j$ and
> $\sum_1^\infty \mathcal{m}(T_j)\leq \mathcal{m}(E)+\epsilon.$ For each
> $j$ by applying Theorem 1.18, to the sides of $T_j$, we can find a
> rectangle $U_j\supset T_j$ whose sides are open sets such that
> $\mathcal{m}(U_j)<\mathcal{m}({T_j})+\epsilon2^{-j}$. If
> $U=\bigcup_1^\infty U_j$, then $U$ is open and $\mathcal{m}(U) \leq
>  \sum_1^\infty \mathcal{m}(U_j)\leq \mathcal{m}(E)+2\epsilon$.

My question is why does this following line hold true?

> For each $j$ by applying Theorem 1.18, to the sides of $T_j$, we can
> find a rectangle $U_j\supset T_j$ whose sides are open sets such that
> $\mathcal{m}(U_j)<\mathcal{m}({T_j})+\epsilon2^{-j}$

My thinking is that in the case of $R^2$, fix some rectangle $T_j=A \times B$ for $A,B \in \mathcal{L}$.

Then by theorem 1.18, for $\epsilon >0$, there exists $A\subset U_1$ and $B \subset U_2$ open such that $\mathcal{m}(A)\leq \mathcal{m}(U_1)\leq \mathcal{m}(A)+\epsilon$ and $\mathcal{m}(B)\leq \mathcal{m}(U_2)\leq \mathcal{m}(B)+\epsilon$.

Now $\mathcal{m}(T_j)=\mathcal{m}(A\times B)=\mathcal{m}(A)\mathcal{m}(B)\leq \mathcal{m}(U_1)\mathcal{m}(U_2)\leq (\mathcal{m}(A)+\epsilon)(\mathcal{m}(B)+\epsilon)$

Am I on the right track? If so how can I choose my $\epsilon$ so that I can expand and continue from here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is basically the fact that the multiplication of $n$ numbers
$$(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \mapsto a_1 \cdots a_n$$
is a continuous map.

But let's prove your statement directly. Let $a_1$,$\ldots$, $a_n\ge 0$. Let $\epsilon> 0$ arbitrary. Let's show that there exists
$b_1$, $\ldots$, $b_n$, $b_i> a_i$ and moreover
$$b_1\cdots b_n < a_1\cdots a_n + \epsilon$$

Let's take $b_i = a_i + \delta a_i $ and see how small must to take $\delta$ so the inequality holds. Now we have
$$b_1 \cdots b_n = a_1 \cdots a_n ( 1 + \delta)^n $$

Now take $\delta$ such that
$$(1+\delta)^n = 1 + \frac{\epsilon}{2 a_1 \cdots a_n}$$

then we get
$$b_1 \cdots b_n = a_1 \cdots a_n + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Now what we do: consider an  $n$-dim rectangle with sides $a_1$, $\ldots$, $a_n$. Let $\epsilon> 0$. There exists an open $n$-dim rectangle containing it such that its volume satisfies
$$V' = b_1 \cdots b_n < a_1 \cdots a_n + \epsilon = V + \epsilon$$